# How to move the red marker on a google maps wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I am modifying a wordpress website which has google maps as a plugin (although it's not on the plugin list). On the map which comes up when visitors open the contact page there is a red marker which indicates the location of the business. But the location has changed and I don't know how to move the marker. I have changed the address in the dialog box for the map - it was found by the system, I saved it, then updated it. But the marker doesn't move. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which plugin are you using ? from where have you updated the address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the lat and lng of the marker in javascript code or modify the url if the map is an iframe.
Can you post the url of that page for help you?

Comment: In the line 143 of that html page i found this:

<div class="et_pb_map" data-center-lat="-27.089095" data-center-lng="150.479872" data-zoom="5"></div>
<div class="et_pb_map_pin" data-lat="-26.739673" data-lng="150.62565799999993" data-title="Office Headquarters">
</div>

and

This is a tutorial of your wp theme about maps for change the data location
http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/tutorial-map.html